# Ant: project dependencies in a flat project layout with ivy

Tags: ant, build, jar, dependencies, ivy

I have two (Eclipse-) projects. Project A depends on project B, but the projects aren't nested i.e. project A is not a subproject of project B. Apache Ivy is responsible for the dependency management. 
When I run the compile task in Project A, is there any way to trigger the compile task (in project B) automatically (for example if the jar file of project B doesn't exist)?
Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ivy task [buildlist](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html).